# SyntaxError in conda update (Anaconda Prompt)

Tags: python, anaconda

I am having an issue where neither Anaconda Navigator nor Spyder will open. In order to fix this, I was attempting to update conda and navigator, however I've run in to a more complicated issue which seems to involve _base.py not functioning properly; see below.

```
    (base) C:\Users\NSing>conda update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\NSing\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\NSing\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 112, in main
    from ..exceptions import conda_exception_handler
  File "C:\Users\NSing\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .common.io import timeout
  File "C:\Users\NSing\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 5, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, _base, as_completed
  File "C:\Users\NSing\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\concurrent\futures\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "C:\Users\NSing\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 381
    raise exception_type, self._exception, self._traceback
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If anybody has a suggestion on how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated, I really don't want to reinstall anaconda since I've got so many extra packages that I would have to reinstall as well.

I'm running Python3.x on Windows 10 and this error came about after attempting to alter my PATH variables to get pydot to recognize graphviz.

Comment: You appear to have installed a Python 2 backport of `concurrent.futures` on Python 3.

Comment: @user2357112, do you have a recommendation to fix this? I attempted to conda update/install futures however it appears to be in conflict with spglib and thus won't let me install.

Comment: I'd probably get a fresh environment, reinstall what's necessary, and try to figure out which step introduces the Python 2 package.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that ended up fixing this problem was to remove the concurrent folder from lib\site-packages. After removing it, conda no longer looked to call the folder and so the error disappeared. Navigator and Spyder are now opening again.

Comment: Manually screwing with your site-packages is going to give you even more problems down the line.